# listviewを配列として扱うには？

Tags: c#

listviewに表示されているテキスト情報を配列としてListで処理しようと考えています。

```
            var strings = new List<string>(listView1.Items);
            strings.Remove("C");
            strings.Insert(strings.IndexOf("A") + 1, "C");
            Console.WriteLine(String.Concat(strings));
```

listView1.Items部分にはどう記述するのが正解なのでしょうか？

Comment: .NET Frameworkに`ListView`は少なくとも3種類ありますが、Windows Formアプリケーション用でしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Windows.Forms.ListView`であれば`listView1.Items[i].Text`で各項目のテキストにアクセスできます。`LINQ`を使えば

```
var strings = listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(e => e.Text).ToList();
```

のように書けます。